# Regex for accepting only numbers

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression which accepts only numbers 0-9 without any special character or decimal. Also single 0 should not be allowed but 0 followed by other numbers are allowed.

Comment: Please post your current regular expression and explain parts that you can't get matching correctly. Also consider adding languge you are using as regular expression engines vary slightly between languages.

Answer (score 7):

`0*[1-9]\d*` should do the work.
`[1-9]` would enforce that a number must start with 1-9; or if it starts with 0, must be followed with a number between 1-9. `\d*` then allows the occurrence of any number including 0 in the complete number.

Answer (score 0):

I usually work in C++ using the boost/regex.hpp library. This should work well for it.

```
boost::regex e("(\d*)([1-9])(\d*)");
```