# How to create regex for accepting only numbers and not anything else(not even spaces)?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have seen the question [Regex for accepting only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618949/regex-for-accepting-only-numbers) . But this is not what I want.

My regex is accept anything except number and replace it with null. Like **`/[^0-9]/g`  then replace with `null` its working for all**, **except for spaces**. The regex is not allowing any char from a-z or A-Z or any special characters. But its allowing space to be entered before or after or in-between.

`var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');`
Here it accepts all chars except numbers and replaces it with '' blank. However, when i add `space` its not getting replaced with a blank.

Eg: if I enter 'a', it gets replaced by null.
 But if I enter `<space>1` or `<space>` or `1<space>` its accepting and not replacing the space with null. Below is the validation:

```
    customValidationDirective.directive('numbersOnly', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

       if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
       var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
       if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
       }         

       return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that should work... but can be simplified to `/\D/g` like `' 1'.replace(/\D/g, '')`

Comment: That regular expression *should* allow for letters, or anything really which is not a number.

Comment: This should work   /^[0-9]+$/gi

Comment: \D or \d is not accepting anything except spaces. :P not even numbers. Idk why. I tried that too.

Comment: Please show us how you are using the regular expression and making the replacing.

Comment: the regex is accepting all except numbers, and then replace with null. And if its number, then don't replace. But ideally it should accept space too and replace it with null, but its not working.

Comment: var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

Comment: Your code works alright. Tested on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca57he7n/)

Comment: `"\n1\ngdfgd1  gghf 5  54".replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') === "11554"` ? It's actually working.

Comment: Ok, thanks, its working on fiddle. Its replacing the space with blank. But on my side its not replacing with blank. Its letting the user add any number of spaces. Is it because of angularJS or some other thing?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code? Perhaps you're doing something else to your string and aren't noticing it.

Comment: I've modified the question and added the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `/[^\d]+/g`. This mean, match only number not anything else, it the same as `/[0-9]+/g`.

Comment: I have added some more detail, please see. Thanks for the help. But \D or \d is not working.

Answer (score 0):

adding $ at the end will resolve your issue because it avoid partial match. try something like this.

```
^[0-9]*$
```

Comment: it's still accepting space and not replacing with '' . var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]*$/g, '');  Ideally it should accept everything except digits from 0-9, and replace it with ''. But its not replacing spaces with blank.

Comment: Are you able to provide type of string you need and currently you are getting for your input?

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript Code**

```
function NumberOnly(e)
 {
var key;
var keychar;

if (window.event)
    key = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e)
    key = e.which;
else
    return true;
keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
keychar = keychar.toLowerCase();

// control keys
if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) ||
(key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27) || (key == 32))
    return true;

    // alphas and numbers
else if ((("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

**Html**

```
onkeypress="return NumberOnly(event)"
```